# Can Node.js force larger POST request chunk size?

Tags: node.js, http

This may be beyond the scope of what Node.js can control, but any pointers to other solutions to this problem are appreciated as well.

I'm uploading large files to a Node.js service via HTTP POST.  When this runs locally or on the LAN, the chunks the server receives are always 65536 bytes in size and uploads are fast.

When I upload the same file to the same code running on a remote server (a Google Cloud VM, or real hardware at a co-lo) the received chunks are between 1448-2869 bytes and uploads are much slower (far below the bandwidth limits of the connection).

I'm not sure where the decision is being made to send smaller chunks across the WAN connection, if it's a calculation performed by the client software (both curl and node.js clients produce the same result), or if it's routing hardware in-between slicing up the packets, or something completely different.

I'm wondering if there is anything I can do to force larger chunks through to the server, or perhaps an alternative approach that overcomes the server thrash associated with processing these small chunks?

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of experimentation and discussing this with a network engineer, the heart of the issue is the limits imposed by MTU size when the connection goes beyond a direct Ethernet link.

My solution was to modify the application to use multiple simultaneous requests to essentially "fill the gaps" created by the network overhead of the smaller chunks.  The result was substantially faster network transfers at the cost of a little increased complexity.